# Understanding build section in an rpm spec file

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

In an rpm spec file, I see the following lines:

```
%build
./configure
make
```

Can someone explain to me what each of the lines do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 %build
```

= start of the build section. The list below:

```
 ./configure
 make
```

are just the commands that you want to be executed to **build** your application. If you don't understand those steps, you need to get some more basic knowledge before trying to use spec files I am afraid. You can start reading here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info !

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, consider accepting the answer. That way other people see that your question is solved.